# JSX Loop with if else check

Tags: reactjs, loops, if-statement, filter, jsx

I'm struggle with a small problem. Hope someone can help me out here.

This is the normal loop I made:

```
      { userLinks.map((item, i) => (
        <li key={i.toString()}>
          <a href={item.url} title={item.label}>
            <span>{item.label}</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      ))}
```

This works good, what I'm trying to do is check if `userLinks > item.hideTrial = true`
And if current user a trial user:

```
const userdata = {
  userid: 921121,
  name: 'John',
  surname: 'Doe',
  fullname: 'John Doe',
  gender: 'mr',
  trial: true,
  expiredate: '14-07-2021',
};
```

That this user because it's a trial user, don't show items where item.hideTrial === true

What if tried, but off course without success:

```
      { userLinks.map((item, i) => {
        if (userdata.trial && item.hideTrial !== true) {
          return (
            <li key={i.toString()}>
              <a href={item.url} title={item.label}>
                <span>{item.label}</span>
              </a>
            </li>
          );
        }
          <li key={i.toString()}>
            <a href={item.url} title={item.label}>
              <span>{item.label}</span>
            </a>
          </li>;
      })}
```

Comment: Where is your else case?

Comment: Looks like both `<li>` are the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return `null` if the condition is `true` to render nothing.
This should work.

```
{
  userLinks.map((item, i) => {
    if (userdata.trial && item.hideTrial) return null;
    else
      return (
        <li key={i.toString()}>
          <a href={item.url} title={item.label}>
            <span>{item.label}</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      );
  });
}
```

Comment: Change it a little bit but this works for me!! Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you only want to show `userLinks` that meet your condition, you might want to use `filter` instead of `map`.

Second, if you want to use an if inside the html, please consider using an inline if such as:

```
      { userLinks.map((item, i) => {
        userdata.trial && item.hideTrial !== true && (
            <li key={i.toString()}>
              <a href={item.url} title={item.label}>
                <span>{item.label}</span>
              </a>
            </li>
          )
          ...
      })}
```

Reference:
https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator